# JApplet Animation Not Running

Tags: java, japplet

So I am trying to get into simple animations and virtual physics and whatnot. I am trying to animate a ball so that it slowly grows as time passes by. The code I have here is pretty much exactly as it is in a Java For Dummies book I have with the exception of a few things such as: getting rid of constants for the size of the applet (this.setSize(500, 500) vs this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT) and declaring WIDTH and HEIGHT earlier). The changes were simple and would not effect the program. (I would know as I've taken a Java course in school). Anyway, I'm starting here with Applets and I can't get the program to run past two iterations. Down in the paint function I have a System.out.println(d) to check how many times the diameter of the ellipse grows. However the only output I see is "21" then "22". The applet continues to run via the applet viewer however nothing else is printed even though it should continue to grow. Anyone know what's wrong?
As a side note I should mention I am using NetBeans 7.2 and selecting "Run File" to run it.

```
package GraphicsTesting;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main extends JApplet
{
    private PaintSurface canvas;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(500,500);
        canvas = new PaintSurface();
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AnimationThread(this), 0L, 20L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}

class AnimationThread implements Runnable
{
    JApplet c;

    public AnimationThread(JApplet C)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        c.repaint();
    }
}

class PaintSurface extends JComponent
{
    int d = 20;
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint
                (RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        d+=1;
        System.out.println(d);//This is to test
        Shape ball = new Ellipse2D.Float(200, 200, d, d);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(ball);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication3;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Main extends JApplet {

  private PaintSurface canvas;
  private Timer timer;

  @Override
  public void init() {
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    canvas = new PaintSurface();
    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
//    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AnimationThread(this), 0L, 20L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        canvas.repaint();
      }
    });
    timer.start();
  }
}

class PaintSurface extends JComponent {

  int d = 20;

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    d += 1;
    System.out.println(d);//This is to test
    Shape ball = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, d, d);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(ball);
  }
}
```

You are calling repaint() on a thread that is not the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
so the UI is not updated. There are other ways to do this, but internally javax.swing.Timer calls the actionPerformed method inside the Event Dispatch Thread so the UI is updated.

**UPDATE:** You could see the applet in action using java webstart: https://tetris-battle-bot.googlecode.com/files/launch.jnlp

Comment: I'd also add that updating the game state inside the `paint` method is a really bad idea as the `paint` method could be updated independently.  Also, a call to `super.paint` would be advisable, in fact, the OP should be encouraged to not extend from a top level container and use something like `JPanel`....or something like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer does work. However, looking at your original code there is one little itty bitty misconception that, it appears, neither of you caught. In the constructor of the animation thread you have `JApplet C` as a parameter rather than `JApplet c`. To clarify, you accidently capitalized the `c`. The capitlization of the `C` caused you to set `this.c = c` which basically assigned it to itself. It wasn't needed to rewrite the entire code at all.

Comment: It's working. You could see the applet using java webstart with this jnlp file https://tetris-battle-bot.googlecode.com/files/launch.jnlp
I built using Netbeans.